# Azure - Copy Tags from other Resource group

Tags: azure, azureportal

I need to copy tags beetween resource groups un Azure.

Is this possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say with a bit of Powershell!

First install the AZ module if you don't have it yet ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.7.0)) or launch launch Cloud Shell in [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/)
Then:

```
$sourceTags = (Get-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName SOURCEGROUP).Tags
Set-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName DESTINATIONGROUP -Tags $sourceTags
```

Replace Get/Set-AzResourceGroup with AzResource only to apply to any other resource type.